# Reading from file and store it to string with unknown length in c

Tags: c

I'm trying to read text from a file and store it into a string so that I can then encrypt and decrypt it using openssl. How can I do this?

Comment: 1) Declare a `char line[MAXLEN+1]` array of the largest string you'd expect, 2) use [fgets(line, MAXLEN, fp)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets) - which includes a "size" parameter - to read your file, a line at a time.

Comment: so should i process it as 2 dimensional array (lines, maxlen+1)? or should i read line by line and store it into a 1 dimensional array (where the line ends, i store the \n and then i store the next line etc)?

Comment: If you're encrypting the entire plaintext document, then I'd  1) call [stat](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to get the filesize, 2) [malloc()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) a buffer for the "document" - add a "fudge factor" to the actual filesize , 4) read a line at a time (as above), 3) [strcat()](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strcat) each line into your buffer, 5) when done, process the buffer.  In other words, copy a line at a time into the "one dimensional buffer".

Comment: i will try this, thanks a lot!

Comment: @paulsm4 why strcat when you can just read the entire file into the buffer with `fread` ? You just stat'd the file. you know its size. so alloc a buffer and load it.

Comment: It might be better to not actually read the whole file but map it directly to memory using `mmap`.

Comment: My original impression was that you wanted to do line-oriented processing.  As things went in the direction of a "one dimensional array": by all means, [malloc()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) a buffer and  [fread()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fread.3.html) the whole file at once :)

Comment: Thanks everyone. Obviously this fread implementation was the best, but i was getting segmentation faults because of some carelessness of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic memory. My "skeleton" code for reading any type of file is this:

```
// Assumes: the file @ file name is a text file; ASCII or UTF-8 (no BOM)
void readwholefile(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *buffer = NULL;
    size_t i, len;

    fp = fopen(filename, "rb");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    len = ftell(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    buffer = malloc(len + 1);
    if (NULL == buffer)
    {
        // Handle malloc failure & exit
        exit(-1);
    }

    fread(buffer, 1, len, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    buffer[len] = '\0';
    // buffer now contains the content of your file; do what you want with it

    free(buffer);
    buffer = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone. Obviously this fread implementation was the best, but i was getting segmentation faults because of some carelessness of me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a POSIX system, you can use `getline`:

```
char *line = nullptr;
size_t line_size = 0
ssize_t len = getline(&line, &line_size, fp);
```

This will read until a newline and malloc enough space for the resulting line.  You can use `getdelim` to read up to some delimiter other than a newline.